# Mode value using Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

For each `ID`, I want to take the mode value for columns `X` and `Y`.

```
  ID         X         Y
 111  0.813997  0.909093
 111  0.813997  0.725128
 111  0.421444  0.725128
 222  0.353979  0.119096
 222  0.353979  0.119096
 222  0.738629  0.764655
 333  0.036765  0.357019
 333  0.915529  0.675708
 333  0.138653  0.533731

custom_sum = dd.Aggregation('custom_sum', lambda x:x.value_counts().index[0], lambda x0:x0.value_counts().index[0])
df.groupby('ID')[['X','Y']].agg(custom_sum).reset_index()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use dd.mode() instead of trying to get the mode via dd.value_counts().

```
dd.groupby(['ID'])[['X', 'Y']].apply(lambda x: x[['X', 'Y']].mode().iloc[0, :]).reset_index().compute()


Output:
Out[25]: 
0   ID         X         Y
0  111  0.813997  0.725128
1  222  0.353979  0.119096
0  333  0.036765  0.357019
```